# How do I print file permissions as a string?

Tags: c, unix, permissions

I have a mode_t perms variable which stores the permission for a file returned from another function. I need to print the file permissions as a tring, of the form

```
rw-r--r-- (0644)
```

but what I get is

```
r--r--r-- (100644)
```

How can I get the right permissions? I've tried googling and don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code:

```
    void print_perms(mode_t perms)
    {
        printf( (perms & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (perms & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
    }
//later
print_perms(permissions);
printf(" (%d)\n", permissions);
```

Comment: I doubt that the code you show is the code you have, since that's not a valid function. Please edit you post to include the *actual* code. Other than that it's good and well-formatted first question. :)

Comment: Note that in Unix permissions, `0644` would typically be an *octal* value. If you're testing with a decimal value (100644 or 644), you won't see the results you expect.

Comment: e.g. a slightly-modified version of your code, with an `%o` for octal output of `perms`, works as expected: https://ideone.com/IAFmLG

Comment: Ok, I see that your solution works. But what can I do about the leading 10? is that not supposed o be there? The number 100644 is what I'm getting as the file permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, UNIX file permissions are conventionally expressed in octal, corresponding format string is "%o", not "%d". rw-r--r-- is really `0644`, but in C language `0644 == 420`, for example (the latter is in decimal).

Second, there are more bits used than 9 specified in the code. You actually should say something like

```
printf(" (%3o)", perms&0777);
```

Comment: I realize this is a pretty old post now, but this particular solution just helped tremendously with some code optimization I'm doing on a project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in the bitwise checks (those where you print the r, w and x) you only print the permissions you are interested in.
When you print the permissions using %d, you print all permissions. Try to check for S_IFREG also. You will see it causes the 'unexpected' 100 in the beginning. In the permissions field, this bit is set to store that this is a 'regular' file.